# Как в начало страницы (сразу после <body>) добавить произвольный код?

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Как написать плагин, который будет добавлять код в начала страницы, сразу после тега `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не написали подробностей, так что, например, так:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('body').prepend('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
} );
```

Если же вы хотите сделать свой плагин с таким функционалом, то это сложно, так как зависит от того, поставляет ли автор темы этот функционал.

Можете изменить тему и добавить свой хук, тогда в коде можно будет его вызвать:

```
<body>
<?php do_action( 'wpse73370_custom_hook' ); ?>
```